# How to style the component passed into a higher order component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, higher-order-components

**Code example:** https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-shadow-o84fn

So I have a super stripped back and basic version of my issue on the link above.

Essentially - I have an un-styled `TextInput` component that I am unable to modify, but have been told I need to use.  I have created my own higher order component that takes in the default input and modifies it to my liking.  I have added several new props, supporting text etc that builds on top of the default.

Everything works as expected, However, I'm unable to style the component I'm passing with Styled Components as I would expect to.

`<Container />` and `<SupportingCopy />` are both styled as I'd like (As they're new elements).  However, unless I add a generic `input` style inside my `Container` I can't seem to achieve what I need.

I've tried adding something similar to `const NewStyledInput = styled(TextInput)` inside my `StyledInput`, but then I'm faced with render issues.

What would be the best way to style `<TextInput />` as I have the rest of the component?

In my example - I'd like to turn the border of my input green when `isFocused` is `true` (As it does the supporting text).  I appreciate this seems quite minor - But I've stripped quite a lot out of this example to make it simpler to explain.

Thanks for any help!

```
const withStyles = TextInput => {
  const StyledInput = ({ ...props }) => {
    const { onFocusCallback, onBlurCallback } = props;
    const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);

    const handleFocusBlur = () => {
      setIsFocused(!isFocused);
    };

    return (
      <Container>
        // I want to style TextInput with Styled Components.
        <TextInput
          {...props}
          onFocusCallback={handleFocusBlur}
          onBlurCallback={handleFocusBlur}
          isFocused={isFocused}
        />
        <br />
        <SupportingCopy isFocused={isFocused}>
          Some additional text
        </SupportingCopy>
      </Container>
    );
  };
```

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but is just plain old "impart a CSS class using your wrapper, and then use normal CSS that targets elements under that class" not an option?

Comment: This might be overkill, but have you tried using the react-jss plugin?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Not a silly question, probably something I should have addressed in my question.  This is the convention that's been set by the business, so I don't have much control over this area.  Certainly would be a quick fix though!

Comment: @ccellist I can achieve something similar by adding an `input` set of styles inside of my `Container` styles.  I've been told by the higher powers that be that this isn't how they think it should work.  (But can't give me any further help... Obviously!)

Comment: Must you style it with HOC (withStyles)? Because there is much easier way

Comment: @DennisVash This is how I've been asked - how would you suggest?  Importing the basic input, applying styles, and passing that into the HOC?

Comment: Why would you want to use HOC in any way, and yes - just import it and style, if you want to reuse some styles you have an API for it.

Comment: @DennisVash I need it to be a HOC as I need to add extra props, elements and states to the basic version

Comment: How it has to do with HOC? You can use a wrapper... anyway I'll try to make an example

Comment: @DennisVash Thank you!

Comment: ```styled(TextInput)`....``` couldn't get you there?

Comment: @DrewReese TextInput isn't defined until we're inside the HOC, and that introduces render issues.  So I'd need to access it beforehand, which I'm unable to do, I think?

Comment: Nick, in your sandbox `TextInput` looks to be a react component, can you not just decorate it? Looks like @DennisVash explained it well enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need HOC in this situation, so it's pretty straight forward:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  position: relative;
`;

const SupportingCopy = styled.label`
  color: ${({ isFocused }) => (isFocused ? 'green' : 'inherit')};
  font-size: 10px;
`;

const greenBorder = css`
  border: 5px solid green;
`;

const MyNewStyledInput = styled(TextInput)`
  padding: 10px;
  ${({ isFocused }) => isFocused && greenBorder};
`;

const StyledInput = props => {
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);

  const onFocusCallback = useCallback(() => setIsFocused(p => !p), []);

  return (
    <Container>
      <MyNewStyledInput
        {...props}
        isFocused={isFocused}
        onFocusCallback={onFocusCallback}
      />
      <br />
      <SupportingCopy isFocused={isFocused}>
        Some additional text
      </SupportingCopy>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit misty-glade-qxjg0]

Comment: Thanks for your help here Dennis - I think I was led down the wrong path by being told to look at using HOC!